# Using texreg function with knit and Lyx

Tags: knitr, lyx, texreg

I'm using Lyx on Mac and I want to get a regressionn output table with function texreg. My code is:

```
<<essai, echo=FALSE>>=
library(texreg)
df=data.frame(y=rnorm(100)+2*x, x=1:100)
reg = lm(y~x, data=df)
texreg(reg)
@
```

But I'didnt get the table in the pdf. I've got lines like this one.

```
##
## \begin{table}
## \begin{center}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the chunk option `results='asis'`:

```
<<essai, echo=FALSE, results='asis'>>=
```

The idea is that the R function `texreg` produces LaTeX, so you want the LaTeX to be interpreted, not escaped.

You can read more about the chunk option [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've inserted knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE,results='asis') and it was going good with function outreg (package rockchalk), but texreg did'nt work and I've received the message LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. I've found the solution. I have to write table=FALSE in the texreg function because I've put the code in a float table.